# Is safe check a NTFS Windows 7 partition using Hiren Boot Mini XP and executing partition check?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, ntfs, check-disk

I'm unable to check HD from the Windows 7 installation cos seem to me that due to problems on the PC HD, Windows 7 is so unstable that don't allow me run its check partition tool. So I decide that this could be a good chance to try Hiren Boot. I see that it come with lot of tools. I just think that booting from its Mini Windows XP I could perform a partition check from there, but is Windows XP partition check compatible with NTFS partitions created and used in Windows 7?

Comment: Should work just fine, but if you suspect errors with the disk itself and not a corrupted file system then use the HDD manufacturer's utility instead of chkdsk.

Comment: @Karan I run TestDisk and then Windows 7 check partition tool (after run TestDisk the error when try to execute the Windows 7 partition tool disappear) and all seem right now. Thanks!